# Calculating width, height and volume of atypical object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, volume

I have atypical objects where I want to calculate its **width**, **height** and **volume**. For the sake of **volume** i have got [this script](https://answers.unity.com/questions/52664/how-would-one-calculate-a-3d-mesh-volume-in-unity.html)

```
public class MeshVolume : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        float volume = VolumeOfMesh(mesh);
        string msg = "The volume of the mesh is " + volume + " cube units.";
        Debug.Log(msg);
    }


 public float SignedVolumeOfTriangle(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
 {
     float v321 = p3.x * p2.y * p1.z;
     float v231 = p2.x * p3.y * p1.z;
     float v312 = p3.x * p1.y * p2.z;
     float v132 = p1.x * p3.y * p2.z;
     float v213 = p2.x * p1.y * p3.z;
     float v123 = p1.x * p2.y * p3.z;
     return (1.0f / 6.0f) * (-v321 + v231 + v312 - v132 - v213 + v123);
 }
 public float VolumeOfMesh(Mesh mesh)
 {
     float volume = 0;
     Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
     int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
     for (int i = 0; i &lt; mesh.triangles.Length; i += 3)
     {
         Vector3 p1 = vertices[triangles[i + 0]];
         Vector3 p2 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
         Vector3 p3 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];
         volume += SignedVolumeOfTriangle(p1, p2, p3);
     }
     return Mathf.Abs(volume);
 }

}
```

As I am not a mathematican so I can't verify that its is working fine and not but one thing is clear that **it is not updating the volume calculation if i scale up or down the object**. So is this the correct way to calculate object volume?
Secondly, I am getting **width** and **height** of the object using meshRenderer bounds

```
Bounds meshBounds = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds;
float width = meshBounds.size.x;
float height = meshBounds.size.y;
```

Is this a correct approach for width and height calculation? How can I cross check it.

Comment: Can you please state in your question why you need the volume in the first place? I am not sure of many practical uses apart from some edge cases. Maybe if you give us a hint, we can help answer the question in a way that will be more useful.

Comment: I guess the issue is that your mesh data will always stay the same. By scaling you are actually just changing a specific user of that mesh data in your Scene. Did you try to take the `transform.lossyScale` into account? It is the scale your object has in world space. And I'ld say the simplest way of testing would be to take models where you know the volume (sphere, cube, cylinder, pyramid etc) and see if the values are correct.

Comment: @derHugo you are right, it is not considering the scale any way it is fine i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have crossed check width and height and volume through revit tool.

For **Width, Height and Breath::**

```
Bounds meshBounds = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds;
float width   = meshBounds.size.x;
float height  = meshBounds.size.y;
float breath  =  meshBounds.size.z
```

In my case i have take MeshRendere bounds you can also calculate it through Collider.

For **Volume:**

```
public float SignedVolumeOfTriangle(Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3)
 {
     float v321 = p3.x * p2.y * p1.z;
     float v231 = p2.x * p3.y * p1.z;
     float v312 = p3.x * p1.y * p2.z;
     float v132 = p1.x * p3.y * p2.z;
     float v213 = p2.x * p1.y * p3.z;
     float v123 = p1.x * p2.y * p3.z;
     return (1.0f / 6.0f) * (-v321 + v231 + v312 - v132 - v213 + v123);
 }
 public float VolumeOfMesh(Mesh mesh)
 {
     float volume = 0;
     Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
     int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
     for (int i = 0; i &lt; mesh.triangles.Length; i += 3)
     {
         Vector3 p1 = vertices[triangles[i + 0]];
         Vector3 p2 = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
         Vector3 p3 = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];
         volume += SignedVolumeOfTriangle(p1, p2, p3);
     }
     return Mathf.Abs(volume);
 }
```